# LDAP AD cannot authenticate a user I just created

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap, jndi

**UPDATE** 11/14: I verified through our ops team that the username/password is valid when logging in via the Active Directory UI. So, it is only programmatically that is failing.

I am working with a simple Active Directory server and am testing the ability to create a new user and then authenticate that user using the credentials I just set.

I can successfully authenticate an existing user (created via the    admin interface on the server); I can create a new user and set the  password (see code snippet below); I can find that user successfully

However, when I attempt to authenticate using the credentials I provided, I am getting the

```
 javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db0]
```

Below is the code to authenticate a user

```
 public UserEntity authenticate ( @NotNull final String username,
                                  @NotNull final String password )
  throws NamingException
 {
     try
     {
        Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();

        env.put( Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple" );
        env.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,      username );
        env.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,    password );
        env.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" );
        env.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL,            "ldaps://<host>:636" );
        env.put( Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,       "ssl" ) ;

        LdapContext context = new InitialLdapContext( env, null );

        // find the account now that the user is authenticated to 
        // construct the UserEntity
        // note: code for findAccountByAccountName() not included as
        //       the creation of the context is what generates the 
        //       exception
        return findAccountByAccountName( context, "<search-base>", username );
     }
  }
```

Here is the code that creates a new user

```
  public static void addUser( @NotNull final String username,
                              @NotNull final String firstName,
                              @NotNull final String password )
    throws NamingException
  {
    // Create a container set of attributes
    //
    Attributes container = new BasicAttributes(true); // case ignore

    // Create the object class to add
    Attribute objClasses = new BasicAttribute( "objectClass" );
    objClasses.add( "top" );
    objClasses.add( "person" );
    objClasses.add( "organizationalPerson" );
    objClasses.add( "user" );

    // Assign the username and first name
    //
    Attribute givenName = new BasicAttribute( "givenName", firstName );
    Attribute sAMAccountName = new BasicAttribute( "sAMAccountName", username );

    // Make the account active
    //
    Attribute userAccountControl = new BasicAttribute( "userAccountControl", "512" ) ;

    // Add these to the container
    //
    container.put( objClasses );
    container.put( givenName );
    container.put( sAMAccountName );
    container.put( userAccountControl ) ;

    // only can do this if connecting via secure ldap
    //
    if ( isSecureLdap() )
    {
       try
       {
          final String quotedPassword = String.format( "\"%s\"", password ) ;
          Attribute pwd = new BasicAttribute( "unicodePwd", quotedPassword.getBytes( "UTF-16LE" ) );
          container.put( pwd );
       }
       catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
       {
          LOGGER.error( "Unable to encode password" );
       }
    }

    // creates a context using the Admin credentials.
    LdapContext context = setup() ;

    // Create the entry
    //
    context.createSubcontext( getUserDN( username ), container );
 }
```

Then in my test code:

```
 // authenticate a known user
 //
 try
 {
     // existing user 'dev' and this works just fine
     authenticate( "dev", "password" ) ;
 }
 catch ( NamingException e )
 {
     // if authentication fails, which it does not in this case
 }

 // create new user
 //
 final String username = "myTestUser" ;
 final String password = "myTestPassword" ;
 try
 {
     addUser( username, "test", password ) ;
 }
 catch ( NamingException e )
 {
     // if creation fails, which it does not in this case
 }

 // try to find that user 
 //
 try
 {
     // code for find() not included since it works
     final UserEntity user = findUser( username ) ;
 }
 catch ( NoSuchUserException e )
 {
     // thrown by find() if it fails -- again, this part still works
 }

 // attempt to authenticate the newly created user
 //
 try
 {
      authenticate( username, password ) ;
 }
 catch ( NamingException e )
 {
     // this is the part that throws the exception
 }
```

I am sure it is something minor that is missing, but after searching around quite a bit on SO and other places, I have not found the magic bean to fix this.

Comment: Does your AD domain have more than one domain controller? If you want to immediately use the account you just created, you have to make sure to hit the same domain controller, since the account will not have replicated to the other DCs.

Comment: in our test environment, we are only running a single controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code for the password:

```
private byte[] encodePassword(String pass) throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
{
     final String ATT_ENCODING = "Unicode"; 
     // Agree with MS's ATTRIBUTE_CONSTRAINT
     String pwd = "\"" + pass +"\"";
     byte bytes[] = pwd.getBytes(ATTENCODING); 
     // strip unicode marker
     byte bytes[] = new byte [_bytes.length - 2];
     System.arraycopy(_bytes, 2, bytes, 0,_bytes.length - 2);
     return bytes; 
}
```

Microsoft Active Directory is funny about passwords.
We usually add the user first then modify the password.
-jim

Comment: This is not necessary. It may be a replication issue.

Comment: Tried the above code, but that generates a WILL_NOT_PERFORM exception. I tried changing "Unicode" to the original UTF-16LE and get the same result. My original code (from posting) appears to succeed.

Comment: and by 'succeed', I mean it appears to create the user. Still cannot authenticate against that user, though.